review queue tests get grayed out
When I'm reviewing questions in the review queues, there sometimes is a question that gets greyed, where you can't even comment I think. This is always one of the tests, but this obviously defeats the purpose of the test. I thought it would be best to point that out here.

I'm not familiar with the situation you describe.  Perhaps a screen shot would clarify.  It is possible to post a link to a review queue instance, and review audits in particular.

This has already been reported on Meta Stack Exchange: Some audits are greyed out in the review queues

@hardmath I have screenshots but got an error uploading them. Since apparently it has already been reported, I'm not gonna try to post them.
